# How to create an event stream on MySQL

Tags: mysql, stream, innodb

Given the following InnoDB table:

```
event_stream
+ id BIGINT PRIMARY AUTO-INCREMENT
+ event TEXT
```

Considering that there are several clients concurrently inserting events into this stream: What technique could we use so that this event stream could be processed in an incremental way by multiple listeners/consumers?

(edit) I.E. I would like to have multiple *clients* attached to this stream that can react to new events once and keep track of their position on the stream.

Considerations:

- Not using MySQL to store the events is not an option;
- locking the entire table is not acceptable;
- I want to keep the control of wether an event was already seem/not seem up to the consumer, there might be multiple consumers for this table;
- Creating new columns is acceptable;
- This table will grow to hundreds of millions of events;

Comment: Sorry @juergen, my explanation was vague. I have edited the question to try to explain it a little bit better. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Don't queue it, just do it."  I have found that a database makes a poor queuing mechanism.  If the 'worker' threads don't take long to perform the tasks, then have the queuers simply perform the tasks; this removes the overhead of the queue, thereby *possibly* making the system faster and scale better.

"Hundreds of millions of events" -- and nearly all of them have been "handled"?  This suggests you have two tables -- one for handled events, one for events waiting to be handled.  The latter would rarely have more than a few dozen rows??  In that case, the processing will work better.

Have two extra columns: which worker owns the process, and when the worker grabbed it.  The time is so that you can take care of the case (*yes, eventually it will happen*) of a worker grabbing a task, then dying -- thereby leaving the task orphaned.  As separate job can 'reap' these orphans.

A single-SQL `UPDATE` can grab one row in the table.  Do this in a transaction by itself, *not* in any transaction(s) in the process.  Similarly 'release' the task in its own transaction.

The grab is something like this (with `autocommit=ON`):

```
UPDATE ToDo SET who = $me, when = NOW()
    WHERE who IS NULL
    LIMIT 1;   -- grab one
SELECT ... FROM ToDo WHERE who = $me;  -- get details on the task
```

The 'release' probably involves both tables, something like this:

```
BEGIN;
$stuff = SELECT ... FROM ToDo WHERE who = $me;
DELETE FROM ToDo WHERE who = $me;
INSERT ... INTO History ... VALUES (most of stuff from $stuff);
COMMIT;
```

In between grabbing and releasing, you have as long as you need to perform the 'task'.  You won't be tripped up by an InnoDB timeout, etc.

If you would like to give further details about your queue and tasks, I may have further refinements.

What I describe should handle any number inserters, any number of workers, and tasks lasting any length of time.

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is *not* reliable for walking through an event list.  An `INSERT` is multiple steps:

1. Start transaction
2. get next auto_incr id
3. do the insert
4. COMMIT -- only now do others see the new id

It *is* possible (especially in replication) for the COMMITs to be "out of order" relative to the auto_incr.

Comment: "Don't queue it, just do it."  -> perfect, useful advice but in this case our work queue takes a very long time to be processed and relies on database replicas.
"This suggests you have two tables" -> one option for sure, we already use it on our current work queue. But in my case I would much prefer to let the worker keep track of the last processed event so that I can have multiple workers for the same event queue.

Comment: I really enjoyed your answer tough, already upvoted it and will accept it if no other answer come up! Thank you very much for your time ;)

Comment: @Kalecser - The outline I gave is designed handle "very long" tasks.